# Nesting a layout within a layout

Tags: filemaker

I was wondering if it was possible to insert a layout within a layout in Filemaker.

For example, to insert a list view layout (with scroll bar) on the right-hand-side of another layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot nest layouts. The closest you can come is to use a portal, and if you want to get really creative, a web viewer.